# TypeError: jsonify() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list returning JSON using Flask

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm working with flask and gevent. My function looks like:

```
@app.route('/index',methods=['POST'])
def index():
....
....
gevent.joinall(threads)
res = [t.value for t in threads]
return jsonify(**res)
```

The response (res) generated is a list of dictionaries looking like:

```
[{u'token': u'146bf00b2cb96e6c425c2ab997637', u'a': u'aaa'},{u'token': u'146bf00b2cb96e6c425c2ab3f7417', u'a': u'bbb'}, {u'token': u'146bf00b2cb96e6c425c2ab3f5692', u'a': u'ccc'} ]
```

When I try to jsonify this I get:

```
TypeError: jsonify() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `**` works on a dict not a list, no idea what the jsonify functions does but you can either use `jsonify(*res)` or` jsonify(*res)`

Comment: Thanks Padraic, what is the name of the * operator , so I can look it up? I knew about **, but not *

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs

Comment: Thanks again, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(**res)` is expecting to `res` to be a single dictionary that it can expand into the keyword arguments to the `jsonify` function. eg

```
res = dict(a=1, b=2)
jsonify(**res)
# is the same as
jsonify(a=1, b=2)
```

In your case can you not just do:

```
jsonify(res)
```

Edit: actually, I think you need to wrap your results up in a dict to return them. You can shortcut it with jsonify as:

```
jsonify(results=res)
```

Gives you

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "a": "aaa",
      "token": "146bf00b2cb96e6c425c2ab997637"
    },
    {
      "a": "bbb",
      "token": "146bf00b2cb96e6c425c2ab3f7417"
    },
    {
      "a": "ccc",
      "token": "146bf00b2cb96e6c425c2ab3f5692"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aidan, that did work! can I ask where you found jsonify(results=res) ?

Comment: Glad it helped. Since before I started even using python / flask I've always used a dict as the base structure in any json based services I've made. As a result I normally do something like `jsonify(objects=[obj1, obj])` – it's just habit really.